# Value passed NULL between View and Controller in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have a dropdownlist which and a button.

The button is used to take me to another view.

I want to pass the value of the selected item in the dropdownlist to the controller because it will be used in another action.

So I try it to do that using `Session` but the value still passed NULL.

This is the View :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("appl", "ProfileGa"))
   { %>

  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%>

  <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"), new { @id = "gg" })%> 


  <input type="button" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Application", "ProfileGa") %>'" />

  </div>
```

This is the the controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Application()
        {
            var vv = new FlowViewModel();


            vv.FaItems = new SelectList(db.Familles.ToList(), "ID_Famille", "ID_Famille");
            vv.SFItems = new SelectList(db.Sous_Familles.ToList(), "ID_SFamaille", "ID_SFamaille");
            vv.PItems = new SelectList(db.Produits.ToList(), "Code_Produit", "Code_Produit");
            vv.FFF = db.Familles.ToList();
            vv.SSS = db.Sous_Familles.ToList();
            vv.PPP = db.Produits.ToList();
            vv.NSItems = db.Ns_AFaires.ToList();

            this.Session["ggg"] = vv.SelectedProfile_Ga;
            return View(vv);


        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult appl(FlowViewModel model)
        {




                Famille fam = new Famille();
                fam = db.Familles.Find(model.SelectedFamille);
                fam.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
                db.Entry(fam).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return View(model);

        }
```

***Note :***

The item selected in the dropdowlist is `SelectedProfile_Ga`.

The action `app` is an action that execute when i click in a button in the view `Application` **and in this action where I want to retrieve the values of the selected item.**

***EDIT***

View Application :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Application
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Application</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("appl", "ProfileGa")) { %>
    <body onload="charge()">

    <fieldset><legend>Veuillez choisir le type :</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Appliquer" id="appl"   />

        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <form id="form1" >

<h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %> </h2>
   <div>         
         <%:Html.Label("Famille :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedFamille, Model.FaItems, new { @id = "ff" })%>

   </div>

   <div>         
         <%:Html.Label("Sous Famille :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSFamille, Model.SFItems, new { @id = "ss" })%>

   </div>

   <div>         
         <%:Html.Label("Produit :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPdt, Model.PItems, new { @id = "pp" })%>

   </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Num_Serie)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Num_Serie, new { @id = "nn" })%>

        </div>



</form>
```

Comment: your data should be in the model, not the session.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs ok but how can i use the value of `SelectedProfile_Ga` in the `ActionResult appl`?

Comment: use a jquery listener on the button click event, and collect the dropdown value.  Then send this value in a redirect.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs thx,,,but i am really a beginner and i never write a jquery code,,,have you an idea ?

Comment: there's a lot of tutorials available for jQuery, and if you want to make a halfway decent MVC project, you will need some familiarity with it.  I recommend you start there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems here:

1. Url.Action("Application", "ProfileGa") is navigating to /Application
   not /appl
2. The javascript in your button does not cause a postback, so you will NEVER get a value in your controller
3. You should heavily consider switching to razor syntax
4. Even if what you have magically worked, you're only sending an id
   but you're trying to bind to FlowViewModel, why not just expect the
   single value you are sending?

I would do this instead:

1. You have a form, use it
2. Alter your controller to only expect what you are actually passing
   accross

Example:
**View:**

```
<% 
   using (Html.BeginForm("appl", "ProfileGa"))
   { 
%>

  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%>

  <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"), new { @id = "gg" })%> 

  <input type="submit" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" />

  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult appl(string SelectedProfile_Ga, FlowViewModel model)
{
  //SelectedProfile_Ga must match the NAME of your dropdownlist, if it does, it will contain the selected value
}
```

This solution may require some modifications on your part as I cannot possibly know your data types, and I guessed at the name of your dropdownlist.

Comment: thx for the answer, but when i change the button definition,,,the moment i click, it will hit the action `appl` not the action `Application` which show the page (HttpGet) and that will produce this error :
The view 'appl' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: I'm not sure what ProfileGa is, but if that's not the name of your controller, I'd get rid of it in the BeginForm(). Also, perhaps it's not clear from your question, which view are you trying to go to? I assumed you were trying to redirect to /appl. Also notice that I removed the [httpPost] attribute, as I didn't see a need for that given what you have.

Comment: yes ,ProfileGa is my controller 
But Application is an action to show the view (as you see in its code, it is contains lists which I used to load value in dropdownlists)
However, the action `appl` is used to record values in my base when I click in a button in the view `Application` ,,,hold on i will put the code of the view `Application`

Comment: Updated based on your edit. Was appl getting called before, just not with the selected value? You have to make sure there is something for the selected value to bind to, so either add it to your model or do as I've shown and add a new parameter for it to bind to. Just remember that wherever you put it, it has to have the exact same name as the input field.

Comment: Was appl getting called before, just not with the selected value? ==> appl is called only at the moment of click in the button of the id="appl",,,There is no modification in the code as I see ?

Comment: No I mean, you said you get an error when you clicked, do you get an error or does it navigate to the appl action in the controller? Also, the edit was made to the appl action in the controller: appl(string, FlowViewModel).

Comment: yes, using the debug, when i click in the button which its id 'appliquer',,, according to ur code its hit the action 'appl'

Comment: Not understanding, isn't that what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry Mike,,,I have to leave now,,because the company where I am now will close,,,please let's continue that after 2 or 3 hours,,,because i need help and I am really stuck ! I will give a better explication,,,if you want email me at : ganfoud.anouar@yahoo.fr
thx and sorry again :((